# Negative Forecast using Holt-Winters

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, data-transformation, exponential-smoothing

I tried to use Holt-Winters for forecasting, but it gives me negative values, but since these are demand quantities they cannot be negative.

```
mydataforecast2 <- forecast::forecast(mydataforecast, h=20, level= c(80,95),fan= FALSE, lambda = NULL)
```

> mydataforecast2
>            Point Forecast      Lo 80     Hi 80      Lo 95     Hi 95
>   Oct 2018      -8724.044  -50231.53  32783.45  -72204.27  54756.18
>   Nov 2018       3826.795  -39752.39  47405.98  -62821.82  70475.41
>   Dec 2018      -2935.782  -48817.20  42945.64  -73105.36  67233.80
>   Jan 2019      -2564.481  -50969.64  45840.67  -76593.78  71464.82
>   Feb 2019       1132.152  -50008.02  52272.32  -77079.99  79344.29
>   Mar 2019      12440.978  -41634.78  66516.73  -70260.75  95142.71
>   Apr 2019      -3240.720  -60441.94  53960.50  -90722.44  84241.00
>   May 2019      -6482.359  -66988.58  54023.86  -99018.63  86053.92
>   Jun 2019     -11312.368  -75293.34  52668.61 -109162.82  86538.09
>   Jul 2019     -15894.025  -83510.41  51722.37 -119304.37  87516.32
>   Aug 2019     -15200.354  -86604.45  56203.74 -124403.50  94002.79
>   Sep 2019     -12319.313  -87655.76  63017.14 -127536.47 102897.84
>   Oct 2019     -25837.357 -118762.44  67087.72 -167954.00 116279.29
>   Nov 2019     -13286.517 -109826.49  83253.45 -160931.66 134358.63
>   Dec 2019     -20049.094 -120359.89  80261.70 -173461.22 133363.03
>   Jan 2020     -19677.793 -123909.49  84553.91 -179086.42 139730.84
>   Feb 2020     -15981.160 -124278.21  92315.89 -181607.21 149644.89
>   Mar 2020      -4672.334 -117173.78 107829.11 -176728.45 167383.78
>   Apr 2020     -20354.033 -137193.79  96485.73 -199045.02 158336.96
>   May 2020     -23595.671 -144902.81  97711.47 -209118.93 161927.59

So I tried to fit it using `BoxCox()`

```
myretailfitted <- BoxCox(myretaildatats,lambda = 0)
myretaildataforecast <- HoltWinters(myretailfitted)
> myretaildataforecast2 <- forecast::forecast(myretaildataforecast, h=20, level= c(80,95),fan= FALSE, lambda = NULL)
```

> myretaildataforecast2
>         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
>   Oct 2018       7.604822 6.993493 8.216152 6.669875 8.539770
>   Nov 2018       8.549561 7.890697 9.208425 7.541916 9.557206
>   Dec 2018       8.133424 7.430231 8.836616 7.057984 9.208863
>   Jan 2019       8.061037 7.316149 8.805924 6.921830 9.200243
>   Feb 2019       8.152589 7.368220 8.936958 6.953000 9.352178
>   Mar 2019       8.444243 7.622287 9.266200 7.187169 9.701317
>   Apr 2019       7.218138 6.360240 8.076037 5.906095 8.530182
>   May 2019       7.129013 6.236618 8.021408 5.764213 8.493813
>   Jun 2019       6.896771 5.971165 7.822376 5.481179 8.312363
>   Jul 2019       6.594478 5.636812 7.552144 5.129854 8.059102
>   Aug 2019       7.076641 6.087954 8.065328 5.564575 8.588707
>   Sep 2019       7.389513 6.370750 8.408277 5.831449 8.947578
>   Oct 2019       6.507436 5.342285 7.672587 4.725491 8.289381
>   Nov 2019       7.452175 6.261395 8.642954 5.631035 9.273314
>   Dec 2019       7.036037 5.820170 8.251904 5.176529 8.895545
>   Jan 2020       6.963650 5.723202 8.204098 5.066549 8.860751
>   Feb 2020       7.055202 5.790652 8.319753 5.121239 8.989166
>   Mar 2020       7.346857 6.058654 8.635060 5.376721 9.316993
>   Apr 2020       6.120752 4.809324 7.432180 4.115095 8.126409
>   May 2020       6.031626 4.697377 7.365876 3.991068 8.072185

Now it gives me above results. How do I scale it back to my original data?

Comment: I would be more interested in why the original forecast was negative. Can you share your data?

Comment: Here is the data --> Week, Quantity 1,7500
2,1041426
3,261636
4,104861
5,93899
6,49511
7,20978
8,28646
9,21179
10,20995
11,24693
12,17301
13,23370
14,84233
15,30068
16,29403
17,26642
18,21107
19,11900
20,7337
21,7231
22,6922
23,27829
24,22216
25,9614
26,19302
27,13418
28,11924
29,16830
30,19214
31,5503
32,10069
33,9153
34,11844
35,14262
36,23057
37,8971
38,21451
39,13944
40,12575
41,12584
42,23048
43,8308
44,7107
45,5456
46,2811
47,3610
48,4794

Comment: Thanks. Holt Winters has a seasonal and trend component. Unless you have more data that you didn't show, you shouldn't be using seasonality with less than one year's worth of weekly data. In fact I would think that if you specified the frequency of the `ts` object as 52 you would get an error from the forecast function. Additionally, the data definitely is trending down. It makes sense that it would forecast a negative trend forward that would lead to negative values. If this is the result of some kind of level shift in demand, not a trend, then you need to control for it.

Comment: Do you suggest using another forecasting method - I have only order quantity for max 2-3 years /monthly data depending upon the product. At one point retailers would push the existing inventory, so no new order will be placed. What's the best way to control is negative trend - I prefer the forecast to be zero than negative. My bad it's monthly data - so I kept the frequency to 12, so that I will have atleast 2 seasons

Comment: ok so seasonality should be okay. For trend you have a few options. First, if there are exogenous factors that are causing shifts down in demand then you could utilize a forecasting method that allows for regressors (the `forecast` package has things you could use). Alternately, you can use a *damped trend* which will lead the trend to die out-- choose a parameter close to zero and it will die out quickly. That way a short term decrease that would take you to zero won't get all the way there.

Comment: Is your data monthly  ?.. if so what is the date of the first month . My analysis was based upon weekly ... please advise and I will re-.analyze ...

Comment: Yes, it's monthly data - starts October 2015

Comment: Hello I tried the damped HW, so it give me positive forecast but the demand forecast seems too high because I am sure in reality we will soon stop doing orders for it --- >Damped Holt-Winters' multiplicative method 

 hw(y = myretaildatats, seasonal = "multiplicative", damped = TRUE,  
 Call:
     beta = 1e-04) 
  Smoothing parameters:
    alpha = 0.1771 
    beta  = 1e-04 
    gamma = 0.0366 
    phi   = 0.8859

Comment: How can you have 48 observed values starting in 2015/10 ...did you mean 2014/10  ????

Answer (score 1):

The formula for converting a Box-Cox transformed time series back to the original time-series is:

x = $e^{\frac{\log{(\alpha * transform +1})}{\alpha}}$

where "transform" is the transformed time-series.

Comment: Hello - I used the formula but it gives me an error :myretransformedata <- exp(log(0.4019424*myretaildataforecast2+1)/0.4019424)
Error in 0.4019424 * myretaildataforecast2 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator  Could you please advise

Comment: I corrected the formula. Does it work now?

Comment: The issue is 0.4019424*myretaildataforecast2 ? Do I need to convert my timeseries object into something else so that the multiplication works

Comment: Try converting it to a vector

Comment: num <- as.numeric(myretaildataforecast2)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' . Gives an error.

Comment: try: as.numeric(unlist(myretaildataforecast2))

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is primarily you are trying to force an inadequate model onto the WEEKLY data . Latent in the data are pulses and two level shifts . Following is a useful model [image] and here [image]

The Actual,Fit and Forecast  graph is here [image] with residual plot here [image] . The ACF of the residuals suggest sufficiency [image]

The forecast plot is here [image] with prediction limits.

The Actual and forecast plot is here showing the 4 pulses and two level shifts[image] while the model is a two parameter autoregression ( lag1 and lag3 ) sometimes called (3,0,0) with an omitted coefficent at lag 2.

The automatic analysis delivered the "controls" that were to be found ... primarily the two downwards level shifts at period 19 and 39 and the 4 pulses at periods 14,23,7 and 42. The are the kind of features that https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/204319/chris-umphlett is suggesting to include in a useful model.

Note that there is a very slight upwards expectation in the forecasts.

In summary "listen to the data" while selecting an appropriate model . Notice there is no need or justification for any power transformations Notice that there is no need for any unwarranted power transformations like logs as is detailed here  [When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers).

Using Box-Cox strategies (without isolating/incorporating a few pulse effects) falsely renders the conclusion that it is proven that there is more variability at the higher level . The conclusion is that increased variability is linked to higher levels of the expected value is false because the effect is not pervasive i.e. true everywhere or nearly everywhere.

IN RESPONSE TO YOUR COMMENT:

1. My model is a hybrid model that includes predictor variables that were identified via Intervention Detection procedures https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/09c4/ba8dd3cc88289caf18d71e8985bdd11ad21c.pdf . For you to duplicate my results simply create a data matrix (6 predictors)  [image] and [image] and use an ar(3) model for the error process (preferably omit the lag2 coefficient) . You could then forecast using specified future values of the predictors and obtain [image] .

2) Apparently you have run into a potential flaw in the software that you used as I was able to estimate a pure ar(3) model . [image] and here [image] . The residuals from this insufficient model suggest the presence of pulses and level shifts (not trends as there is a visual shift in the mean of the residuals rather than a continuous downwards slope) that need to be treated in order to correctly separate gignal and noise. [image]. You should report your potential error to the author of the software so it can be remedied.

3) You didn't answer my question . Is this monthly data ? If so I can re-analyze as their maybe deterministic seasonal pulses in the data that are waiting to be discovered as they may be temporarily obfuscated by the autoregressive structure.

[image]

Comment: I get error when I try to run the forecast function.
arima(x = myretaildatats, order = c(3, 0, 0))
Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2     ar3  intercept
      0.0717  0.3031  0.3798   89520.08
s.e.  0.1882  0.5210  0.4178   90935.45
sigma^2 estimated as 2.04e+10:  log likelihood = -638.3,  aic = 1286.6
>forecastarimaoutput <- forecast::Arima(forecastarima, h=20)
Error in stats::arima(x = x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, include.mean = include.mean,  : 
  unused argument (h = 20)

Comment: Yes it is monthly data

Comment: I will open up another answer .....

Comment: There is no "flaw in the software used" with regards to fitting the AR(3) model, @paty26s is just passing the wrong arguments to the wrong functions.

Comment: that is good to know ....user error ! . I might have said  or a "flaw in the software usage" .

Answer (score 0):

After being advised that the 48 values were MONTHLY.. A useful model was automatically constructed blending arima structure and any waiting-to-be-identified deterministic structure. The model is here [image] and here [image] with statistical summary here [image].

The plot of the residuals is here [image] and forecast plot here [image]

The arima portion is very similar to my first response as it has both a lag 1 and a lag 3 component. [image] . (1,0,0)(1,0,0)3 .

One level shift down at or around period 20. Three pulses  .. 14,23 and 4. Two seasonal dummy factors are also found representing a systematic downwards effect at period 1 and period 7 thus there is seasonality ( i.e. two seasonal dummies ) and not auto-projective seasonality i.e. arima seasonality.

Following is a table of forecasts [image]

The Actual/Fit and Forecast is here [image]

In order to more more fully understand this model ...closely examine the 7,19,31,and 43 values and you will better appreciate the seasonal pulse at period 7 of 12 that occurred each and every year as the values are all on the "low side" reflecting a singular effect given recent values.

time   value

7      20978
19     11900
31      5503
43      8308

After being advised that the data starts at 2015/10  period 7 is April.

Comment: There are 48 observations in the file, start date is good